# How to exec but keeping the same argv0

Tags: zsh

From zshbuiltins manual,

> ```
>    exec [ -cl ] [ -a argv0 ] simple command
>           Replace  the  current shell with an external command rather than forking.  With -c clear the environment; with -l prepend - to the argv[0] string of the command executed (to simulate a login shell); 
>    with -a argv0 set the argv[0] string  of  the  command executed.  See the section `Precommand Modifiers'.
> ```

I tried using `-a`  with a simple script but it doesn't seem to work

```
[balakrishnan@mylap scripts]$ cat printer.sh;echo "-----";cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $0 $1 $2 $3 $4
-----
#!/bin/zsh
argv0="$0"
exec -a "$argv0" printer.sh
[balakrishnan@mylap scripts]$ wrapper.sh 
printer.sh
[balakrishnan@mylap scripts]$
```

Since I set `wrapper.sh` as `argv0`, I expect that to be printed when `printer.sh` echos `$0`. But it still print `printer.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` is setting `argv[0]` correctly, but when `/bin/sh` runs to interpret the script, it sets `$0` to the name of the script being run, ignoring `argv[0]`.

The `zsh` man page doesn’t explicitly describe this behaviour, but the `bash` manpage does:

> #### ARGUMENTS
>
> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the `-c` nor the
>     `-s`  option  has  been supplied, the first argument is assumed to be the
>     name of a file containing shell commands.  If `bash` is invoked  in  this
>     fashion,  **`$0` is set to the name of the file**, and the positional parame-
>     ters are set to the remaining arguments.

---

You can see that `argv[0]` is being set correctly by running a tiny C program instead of a shell script:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way in the standard `sh` interpreter to exec with such an option? My `/bin/sh` is a `dash` shell which doesn't support a way to override `argv0`

Comment: For running shell commands, you can do `sh -c 'echo "${0}"' foo`, which sets `$0` to `foo`. Otherwise I’d probably create a symlink with the desired name in a temporary directory, and execute that.